# jQuery autocomplete change overriding form submit

Tags: jquery

I have implemented jQuery autocomplete combobox and its working fine. Now I have a wierd issue. Whenever the user types in the combobox and immediately submits the form, the change event in autocomplete is fired which overrides the submit of form. How can i make it work?

Comment: call something like `$('form').submit()` inside the change event?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain, but based on your description I think you're experiencing a known bug in the  autocomplete widget: [#7550: Autocomplete change event not triggered in time](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7550).  The gist is that the submit happens before your change handler executes so your handler won't be able to modify anything on the form at that point (technically it can, but the submit already happened in the form's old state).

This is scheduled to be fixed in jqueryUI 1.9 (december 2012?)

If you think this is your problem, leave me a comment and I'll try to update with a decent workaround.